# firestore failed to get subcollection with permission denied error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to get documents with all subcollections using java library.

My firestore has data above

```
/groups/group1/posts/post1
/groups/group1/users/user1
```

this is my rule, I set to permit all request for test.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

this is my java code

```java
Iterable<CollectionReference> collections =
  db.collection("groups").document("group1").listCollections();

for (CollectionReference collRef : collections) {
  System.out.println("Found subcollection with id: " + collRef.getId());
}
```

but I met this error

```java
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
```

---

updated

this is not android sdk, official document is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

and this is my part of `build.gradel`

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:3.2.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '2.7.1'
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the SDK you''re using? The Android SDK doesn't have a `listCollections` call ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference)), and the Admin SDK for Java isn't affected by security rules

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated about what you said, thanks

Comment: Have you check this related [Github post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2788)?

Comment: @RJC oh thanks I solved my problem by using `setCreadentailProvider`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed few code lines for setting credential

```
  .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
```

it make works clealy.